# jQuery addClass doesn't work, but css does

Tags: jquery

### **Does Not Work**

**CSS**

```
.active 
{
    display: block;
}
```

**JS**

```
$("#li_1 ul").addClass('active');
```

### **Does Work**

**JS**

```
$("#li_1 ul").css('display', 'block');
```

Which leads to me my question, why does the css function work and not the addClass? There's no difference between the selectors at all.

Additional info -

- Using jQuery version 1.6.4
- JS in question here resides in a .js file being included in an
  ASP.NET masterpage
- masterpage has link to stylesheet containing the CSS in question
  here (ie - the 'active' style is available to the masterpage)

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle that replicates this issue?

Comment: Check Firebug and see what styles are overriding `.active` on the element. Inline style will always have highest priority.

Comment: Does the code in your question represent *all* that is needed to reproduce the issue?

Comment: Does the class get added in Firebug? If so, are you sure the CSS is available? If so, is the JS firing before the class gets loaded?

Comment: @Madmartigan et. al. - thanks for the suggestions. I used Firebug to see that another style was overriding the display and setting it to 'none'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about using this statement:

```
.active {
  display:block !important;
}
```

I think something overrides your `.active` rule in your CSS stylesheet.

More informations about CSS priorities [right here](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Training/Priority_level_of_selector).

Comment: I agree, it will be something called specificity, which is a great word that you only really get to use in the world of CSS :)

Comment: Boy do I feel dumb. Should have thought to check this. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your HTML it's hard to say for sure why it's not working.  I can say that the JS you've posted should work fine.  I have a working example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/hsyEw/1/

One thing that jumps out is that this selector `$("#li_1 ul")` looks a little weird.  do you really have a `ul` element that is a child of an element with an id that implies it is an `li`?

Your second JS example is applying style directly to the element which will overwrite any CSS Class styles that are being applied, so if you have some other CSS present that is affecting that element this could explain the behavior you are seeing.